# What are all the filesystems in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems

There's not a single comprehensive list of all of Linux's filesystems on the web, majority of the lists are either too short or outdated. Can anyone list all the file systems in Linux and give a description of each?

Here are two lists I've looked through that my professor said were incomplete or outdated:

https://tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/filesystems.html

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/filesystems.5.html

Comment: The most up to date information is probably here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ There is an `index.rst` file that contains a list at the bottom (though it's missing ext4, for instance).

Comment: If that list is missing something as ubiquitous as ext4, it can hardly be considered exhaustive.  But I highly doubt there exists a complete list of _all_ filesystems that can be used in Linux, because I rather suspect there is a nontrivial number of filesystems that have been developed, implemented, and never actually distributed for any number of reasons.  For example, before Google Drive was a thing, I remember playing with a `gmailfs` implementation.  I would be amazed if there were not similar things that never saw the light of day outside of its dev environment.

Comment: @DopeGhoti the directory listing ***is*** the complete list... at least as far as the kernel team is concerned... for third-party, all bets are off.

Comment: I’d say the canonical list is [in `fs`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs), not in the documentation.

Comment: tmpfs is in [mm](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/shmem.c) ;-)

Comment: @DopeGhoti I suspect that gmailfs was implemented in userland using [fuse](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html) -- which raises the question: should filesystems based on fuse (like ntfs-3g) be considered separately or just subsumed undef "fuse" in that "exhaustive" list?

Comment: There's [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems), but it's not limited to Linux. You could probably start there and narrow it down until only Linux types remain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download [the Linux source](https://www.kernel.org/), unpack, run `make menuconfig` - under `File systems` you'll find all the supported file systems along with their descriptions.

Here's what you'll see in Linux 5.8.16:

```
 .config - Linux/x86 5.8.16 Kernel Configuration
 > File systems ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  ┌──────────────────────────── File systems ────────────────────────────┐
  │  Arrow keys navigate the menu.  <Enter> selects submenus ---> (or    │  
  │  empty submenus ----).  Highlighted letters are hotkeys.  Pressing   │  
  │  <Y> includes, <N> excludes, <M> modularizes features.  Press        │  
  │  <Esc><Esc> to exit, <?> for Help, </> for Search.  Legend: [*]      │  
  │ ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │  
  │ │    [ ] Validate filesystem parameter description                 │ │  
  │ │    < > Second extended fs support                                │ │  
  │ │    < > The Extended 3 (ext3) filesystem                          │ │  
  │ │    < > The Extended 4 (ext4) filesystem                          │ │  
  │ │    < > Reiserfs support                                          │ │  
  │ │    < > JFS filesystem support                                    │ │  
  │ │    < > XFS filesystem support                                    │ │  
  │ │    < > GFS2 file system support                                  │ │  
  │ │    < > Btrfs filesystem support                                  │ │  
  │ │    < > NILFS2 file system support                                │ │  
  │ │    < > F2FS filesystem support                                   │ │  
  │ │    [ ] Direct Access (DAX) support                               │ │  
  │ │    [ ] Enable filesystem export operations for block IO          │ │  
  │ │    -*- Enable POSIX file locking API                             │ │  
  │ │    [ ]   Enable Mandatory file locking                           │ │  
  │ │    [ ] FS Encryption (Per-file encryption)                       │ │  
  │ │    [ ] FS Verity (read-only file-based authenticity protection)  │ │  
  │ │    [ ] Dnotify support                                           │ │  
  │ │    [ ] Inotify support for userspace                             │ │  
  │ │    [ ] Filesystem wide access notification                       │ │  
  │ │    [ ] Quota support                                             │ │  
  │ │    < > Old Kconfig name for Kernel automounter support           │ │  
  │ │    < > Kernel automounter support (supports v3, v4 and v5)       │ │  
  │ │    < > FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) support                    │ │  
  │ │    < > Overlay filesystem support                                │ │  
  │ │        Caches  --->                                              │ │  
  │ │        CD-ROM/DVD Filesystems  --->                              │ │  
  │ │        DOS/FAT/EXFAT/NT Filesystems  --->                        │ │  
  │ │        Pseudo filesystems  --->                                  │ │  
  │ │    -*- Miscellaneous filesystems  --->                           │ │  
  │ │    [ ] Network File Systems  ----                                │ │  
  │ │    -*- Native language support  --->                             │ │  
  │ │    [ ] UTF-8 normalization and casefolding support               │ │  
  │ │                                                                  │ │  
  │ │                                                                  │ │  
  │ │                                                                  │ │  
  │ └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ │  
  ├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤  
  │       <Select>    < Exit >    < Help >    < Save >    < Load >       │  
  └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a complete list, either. I guess that checking that `Network File Systems` box will open a whole new horizon of filesystems ;-)

Comment: This list - no, once you run `make menuconfig` - you'll see them all. I was too lazy to explore and post each submenu.

Quite a lot of FSes are under `CD-ROM/DVD`, `DOS/FAT/etc` and of course Network File systems